# I'm trying to figure out convert coordinates of facial features in Dlibs to standard (X, Y) coordinates

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a project to create a face tracking camera using servos, aurdino, python, and a serial communication. Currently my python script uses Dlibs to find and place a dot on the center of my face. Using a print() function I can display the X and Y coordinates of this point, but it seems the Y axis is inverted and I need a way to un-invert it so the coordinates are readable by my Aurdino program. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What do you mean by "the y axis is inverted?" Some pictures or ccode might help clarify your question

Comment: Sorry my bad for not being clear. What I mean is when placing a point, the higher the Y value the lower the point appears on the screen

Comment: Ah! That's because the origin (0, 0) in images is in the top-left corner. The positive X axis points to the right, and the positive Y axis points down. You could define any other point as your origin and simply subtract the coordinates of your new origin from each old pair of coordinates and multiply by -1 where required to get the coordinates in the new axes.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, do you have any idea how to set the orgin point of a video capture device using OpenCV?